# Why am I getting a NullPointerException when I try to add an instance of a class into this 2D array of the class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, nullpointerexception, multidimensional-array

Trying to make a program to read a text file of a maze, convert each char of it to a string and print into a console. Can't get the 2D array to work. What is it I am doing wrong? Is there something I am not catching else where? I am fairly new to programming and Java so this may be all kinds of wrong. Also keep in mind this is not finished yet at all, still very much in progress, so other errors are probably present.

Enumerated type Square
    public enum Square{

```
WALLS, OPENSPACE, START, FINISH;

private String str;

private Square(String str){
    this.str = str;
}

public String toString(){
    return str;
}



public static final Square fromChar(char ch){

    switch(ch){
    case '#':
        return WALLS;
    case '.':
        return OPENSPACE;
    case 'o':
        return START;
    case '*':
        return FINISH;
    }
    return null;

}

}
```

Maze Class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Maze {
private Square[][] mazeArray = new Square[10][10];

public Maze(Square[][] mazeArray){
    this.mazeArray = mazeArray;
}



public void readMaze() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File reader = new File("testMaze.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(reader);
    String line = "";
    line = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    String array[] = line.split(" ");
    int width = Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
    int height = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
    System.out.println(width);
    char[] cArray = new char[10];


    while (input.hasNextLine()){
        line = input.nextLine();
        cArray = line.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(cArray);
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            for (int x = 0; x < cArray.length; x++){
                Square sq = Square.fromChar(cArray[x]);
                System.out.println(sq);``
                mazeArray[i][x] = sq ; //This is where it gives me a nullPointerException
        }
    }
    mazeArray.toString();

}
}
```

Main Method
    public class MazeMain {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Maze myMaze = new Maze(null);
    myMaze.readMaze();
}

}
```

testMaze.txt

```
7 4       ;
#######   ;
#...#o#   ;
#*#...#   ;
#######   ;
```

Comment: what does your testMaze.txt look like?

Comment: What are you passing to the Maze constructor?

Comment: How do you call `Maze(Square[][] mazeArray){ `?